# Hibernate SQL transforming one column to two different fields

Tags: sql, hibernate, javabeans

I have a DTO that has two objects inside. These objects have some common values. In order to have the same value in them, I have the duplicate values in the query with different alias'.

This works perfectly but slows down the query when I have a million values in the db. So I was wondering if there is a way to have those values only once in the query and transforming into two different objects. For example:

```
class EmployeeDTO {
   Phone personal;
   Phone mobile;
}

class Phone {
   String number;
}
```

Imagine that I have also a DAO class and it reads the employee table which has only one number column. But I am having it twice with different alias' like

```
 SELECT number AS personal.number, number AS mobile.number ...
```

Well, I can transform only one number and copy it later to the other field but then I have to use a loop to do it and this won't help for performance. What is the common way to solve this?

Comment: How are you fetching the results from this query? What are using?

Comment: I am using 'AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer'. You can find it on the github. https://github.com/samiandoni/AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer and there is also a usage example there.

Comment: Are these the only fields in your employee table? And it will be helpful to share the implementation code too :)

Comment: Well this is just an example as a show case. Imagine that my employee table has about 50 columns and I have 60 fields in EmployeeDTO (some nested). So I am duplicating 10 columns in the query with different alias' and I don't want to do it this way.

Comment: Having it at DBMS  SELECT side is quite reasonable as some  day data source may change.